# Attached property always has a default value in a style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, attached-properties

I'm working with WPF and I want to use attached properties to work with some styling things in the validation of the controls (my example of the problem is really simple, binding a simple text).

This is my attached property:

```
public class ToolTipExtension
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowToolTipProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ShowToolTip", typeof(string), typeof(ToolTipExtension), new PropertyMetadata("Deffault"));    

    public static void SetShowToolTip(DependencyObject element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ShowToolTipProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetShowToolTip(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (string) element.GetValue(ShowToolTipProperty);
    }    
}
```

I have a simple style dictionary like this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:at="clr-namespace:CarpetaTecnicaWPF.AttachedProperties"
                    >   
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="Blah" >
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(at:ToolTipExtension.ShowToolTip)}" FontSize="50"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to bind the `Text` property to my attached property.

In my `Page`, I'm using the style like this:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource Blah}" at:ToolTipExtension.ShowToolTip="Prueba?"/>
```

The thing is, the value `Prueba?` does not appear. When I inspect the tree, I see this:

[image: screenshot]

But in runtime, the result of the binding is `Deffault`

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work at run-time ? Or what is *"in the UI"* ?

Comment: @Sinatr Exactly, the result of the binding, and the value displayed, is `Deffault` instead of `Prueba?`

Comment: Can't reproduce it. I did a quick test, using `Template` (not `ErrorTemplate`) property, works fine at run-time.

Comment: Change the binding of `ControlTemplate` to `{TemplateBinding at:ToolTipExtension.ShowToolTip}` and see if works.

Comment: Can you take a bit of time and prepare [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinKouketsu i try, but the result its the same :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding is incorrect.

The `TemplatedParent` in this case is not what you actually need. The `ControlTemplate` for the error is not applied to the text box itself, it's a stand-alone control template. So you are just getting a default value from a wrong `FrameworkElement`.

To access the text box your error template is applied to, you need to use the `AdornedElementPlaceholder` in your `ControlTemplate`. From that `AdornedElementPlaceholder`, you can access your text box via the `AdornedElement` property.

Here is an example:

```
  <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(at:ToolTipExtension.ShowToolTip)}"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

Comment: Just to learn, how should I debug this? How do I find that value really came another way? Did exist some book or something to learn this type of things? or is just experience?

Comment: Well... There are lots of good books out there. Regarding the error template, you just could read the Microsoft Docs about [validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframework-4.8#providing-visual-feedback) and [AdornedElementPlaceholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.adornedelementplaceholder?view=netframework-4.8)